# Center align text in an element with display property value of inline(only)

Tags: css

Trying to center the text I have in an element with a **display** **property value** of just **inline** but to no avail.

Below would've been a perfect example of what I want if the text would align in the middle.

```css
#inliner {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="inliner">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim nulla fugit quidem hic temporibus aliquam a! Consectetur, tempore temporibus optio quod repudiandae placeat distinctio eligendi quae nihil sit rerum ex cumque libero cupiditate delectus doloremque incidunt esse recusandae omnis enim magnam alias perspiciatis quas id reprehenderit neque iusto minima dolores!    
</div><!-- End Inliner -->
```

I tried adding an inner DIV to help me achieve that. Far from desired result because the green background disappears and can only be seen the bottom area.

```css
#inliner {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#inliner-in {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div id="inliner">
    <div id="inliner-in">
    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim nulla fugit quidem hic temporibus aliquam a! Consectetur, tempore temporibus optio quod repudiandae placeat distinctio eligendi quae nihil sit rerum ex cumque libero cupiditate delectus doloremque incidunt esse recusandae omnis enim magnam alias perspiciatis quas id reprehenderit neque iusto minima dolores! 
        </div><!-- End Inliner -->
</div><!-- End Inliner -->
```

Comment: Your second answer is working?

Comment: is there a specific reason to use inline for parent text container?

Comment: Can't you apply `text-align:center;` to the parent element of `#inliner`?

Comment: Also, text should be in a text element, not a bare text node.

Comment: text-align/width will not come into effect since the container is inline. the container expand in width to accommodate the content. If it is not neccessary for #inliner to be "inline", then "block" would solve the problem nicely.

Comment: @SleekGeek FYI your answer on the list / question was valid. Not sure why you deleted it

Comment: @ZarcSaucier It is okay. Your answers solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the background-color and display:inline to the child DIV.

```
#inliner {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

#inliner-in {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This saved the day. Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

Check on your console if your css if being correctly applied, because I think what you have there is supposed to work but if not...

You can try by aligning the entire div like:

```
#inliner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```